# How to create a minimizing function in python

Tags: python, scipy, calculus, scipy-optimize-minimize

How should I write this minimize function in order to always get 0 as the result of the calc function?

```
def calc(x, a, b, c, d):
    z = b + c + d
    y = x * a - z - x * a * 0.015
    return y


def minimize(a, b, c, d):
    z = b + c + d
    # 0 = a * 0.095 - z
    # what if z is > a
    m = '?'
    return m


A = 100
B = 90
C = 5
D = 1

print(calc(minimize(A, B, C, D), A, B, C, D))
```

I tried using spicy.optimize.differential_evolution and it worked for minimizing the value of calc(), but I believe a simple calculus approach should do the trick, I'm just not remembering how to do it.

Comment: I don't follow what you're trying to minimize. Calling calc with the arguments `calc(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` will always give you zero, but I have a feeling that's not what you mean. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I want to create a function to minimize the result of calc, regardless of the values assigned to A, B, C and D.
So I want a function to return the value of calc function argument x that will make calc function result to be closest to zero as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a simple "solve for X" problem, and if the definition of `calc` is fixed then it's easier to just solve it yourself and then code in the solution than to mess around with sympy and the like.

No tricky calculus is required; just use the same techniques for balancing equations that you learned in basic algebra (namely, that as long as you do the same thing to both sides, the equation remains balanced -- I remember my 8th grade math teacher demonstrating this concept with a balance scale and a handful of weights).

Given this function:

```
    z = b + c + d
    y = x * a - z - x * a * 0.015
    return y
```

which is the same as:

```
    return x * a - (b + c + d) - x * a * 0.015
```

find the value of `x` in terms of `a, b, c, d` that produces a `return 0`.

```
        0 = x * a - (b + c + d) - x * a * 0.015
b + c + d = x * a - x * a * 0.015
b + c + d = x * a * (1 - 0.015)
b + c + d = x * a * 0.985
        x = (b + c + d) / (a * 0.985)
```

Plug that into the `minimize` function:

```
>>> def minimize(a, b, c, d):
...     return (b + c + d) / (a * 0.985)
...
```

and test it with your `calc` test case:

```
>>> A = 100
>>> B = 90
>>> C = 5
>>> D = 1
>>>
>>> print(calc(minimize(A, B, C, D), A, B, C, D))
7.771561172376096e-15
```

Note that floating points aren't perfectly precise, and `calc` involves floating point math, so getting exactly zero may not always be possible.  If you want precise decimal math check out Python's `decimal` module.